# Are there sections in StackExchange suitable for questions about maintaining and fixing different things?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, site-recommendation

Maintain and fixing stuff such as software, tech, etc..

I asked a question in Electrical Engineering about how to find a problem with a pair of speakers, but questions about fixing speakers are considered to be off topic there.

Sometimes people can't find an answer for a problem with maintaining of fixing something. The fact, that many people "lurk" in Stack Exchange, makes the platform a great place to search or ask for an answer.

Here I'll have to ask more than one question. I think they are better asked all together.

I might be missing the section/s that are suitable for such questions. Could someone address me to them, if they exist? If there are none, can we expect any in the future? If not, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Home Improvement](http://diy.stackexchange.com) is probably the closest, but unfortunately it draws the line at questions about maintaining *large appliances* so that would be decidedly off-tpoic there too.

The [Consumer Electronics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33064/consumer-electronics) proposal is probably the *most likely* proposed site *in the pipeline* to cover that topic (but is still in definition.)

The reason there is no generalist site for fixing "things" is that each Stack Exchange site is geared toward attracting experts in a particular area of interest, if we lump everything together in a "fixing stuff" site, the signal/noise ratio would be too low to draw most enthusiasts in.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out Area 51. It's a new site staging zone. There's one for [audio-video production](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4/audio-video-production) and one for [audiophiles](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42145/audiophile).

You could try posting there and also get involved in the beta process for launching a new site.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing "things" is pretty broad, but depending on the circumstances there may be a suitable site. A list of all StackExchange sites is available here:

https://stackexchange.com/sites

[diy.stackexchange.com](http://diy.stackexchange.com) is appropriate for many building/fixing questions, but I don't think a question about speakers is appropriate there.

If all else fails, try [Quora](http://www.quora.com)